# Usage of SuppressFinalize with DisposeAsync

Tags: c#, dispose

I'm getting a message

> DisposeAsync() calls GC.SuppressFinalize(object), a method that is typically only called within an
> implementation of 'IDisposable.Dispose'. Refer to the IDisposable
> pattern for more information.

from Visual Studio. Yes it is not Dispose but DisposeAsync but still the documentation states to call SuppressFinalize. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-disposeasync

So who is correct the documentation or the compiler?

Implementation of IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync in my class along the line of the documentated pattern in the docs linked above

```
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore();

        Dispose(disposing: false);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

Message from Visual Studio (16.9.1) taken from Error List

[image]

Description of the message https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1816

Comment: You really shouldn't be writing your own finalizers in general, but all the more so when the disposal is asynchronous, so it should be moot for you.

Comment: Is there a *code* associated with the message you're showing us? If so, please share. It will help us identify *where* this message is coming from (e.g. from the compiler, from a Roslyn analyser, from a third-party tool)

Comment: Lovely Microsoft. In the docs they linked this example https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/035b729d829368c2790d825bd02db14f0c0fd2ea/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Writer/Utf8JsonWriter.cs#L297-L345 to show you what to do. And in that example they do nothing of the stuff they say you should do.

Comment: @Ralf You apparently didn't pay attention to the notes that almost all of that is *only needed if you actually have direct access to unmanaged resources*, rather than a dispose method that is merely holding onto other disposable objects or managed resources that require cleanup (which should be 99.9+% of your types implementing IDisposable).  (Granted, MS should be making that more prominent, but at least it's better than in years past where it wasn't mentioned at all)